# jQuery or Javascript: detecting if the text caret has left an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, caret

Is there a way, via jQuery or regular Javascript, to detect if the user's text caret has moved out of an element (such as a td, div, span, etc.)?

The scenario is this: I have a table of textboxes which are grouped in pairs inside a span element.  I am performing validation on the entries in the pair but I do not want validation errors to pop up until the user has switched to another pair of textboxes (i.e. another span).

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, but in my mind I'm thinking perform validation on the pair once the user has switched out.  But I need to know when the caret has moved over into another span element.  I can't rely on the mouse position since a user could easily flick the mouse pointer to some other location while making entries.

Answer (score 0):

you can use loses focus event

```
<input type="text" onblur="myFunction()">
```

or

```
$("input").focusout(function(){
    //do Somthing;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question.